# How to synchronize countdown timers in multiple browser tabs?

Tags: reactjs, timer, redux, browser-tab

I am developing an app on React where **countdown timers** are the main component (at the same time there can be 10-20 timers on the page). From the server I get: how long the timer should go and how much is left in seconds. Then every second I recount how much is left. The source data is stored in redux, and calculated in the component local state.

These timers should show the same values for every user.

The problem is when I **duplicate the tabs in the browser**, the api request does not occur, respectively, the timers in a new tab are rolled back to the old state.
Updating data every second in redux seems to me not to be the best option, but I don’t see others yet.

Comment: updating your store every second is no problem at all. But I don't see anyways how that could solve your problem. Every tab has its own context and its own redux store. What you could do is storing the end time in local storage and read that value on initializing your timer.

Comment: I considered this option. But this way I should use current client time, which can be different from server time.

Comment: That doesn't matter if you calculate the end time on the client based on what the server sent and store that value. Also that is what timezone information is there for.

Comment: Yes, but user can manually set minutes and seconds on devise.

Comment: But why does that matter if you entirely calculate the end time based on the client time. If the user does that for whatever reason it will still be the same (wrong) time in every tab.

Comment: Because I would check every second, whether current time value matches end time value. And current time may not be  valid.

Comment: These timers should show the same values for every user.

Comment: Why would the end time not be valid? The server tells you "60 seconds remainimg". So you calculate which time is in 60 seconds based on the current client time. No server time involved and it also does not matter if the client time is correct. I find it to be a weird expectation anyways to assume, the client has an invalid time set while being online.

Comment: I cant properly understand, your proposition is to simply subtract every second from end value, received from server and save result inside local storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that the server sends you the remaining time in seconds. So you can calculate on the client side when the countdown should end in client time. You can store that in local storage. When a new tab is opened you can use that value to initialize your timer.

It does not require the client time to be correct or in sync with the server time as all tabs share the same (possibly wrong) client time. You are only interested in the difference in seconds between the current client time and the client time you saved to correctly initialize your timer.

A solution to calculate it could roughly look like this:

```js
// when receiving the remaining seconds in the first tab

const onReceivedRemaining = (remaining) => {
    const now = new Date(); // current client time
    now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + remaining); // timer end in client time

    localStorage.set('elapsing', JSON.stringify(now));
}

// when initializing the timer in a second tab

const getInitial = () => {
    const elapsing_string = localStorage.get('elapsing');
    if (!elapsing_string) return null;

    const now = new Date();
    const elapsing = Date.parse(elapsing_string);
    return (elapsing - now) / 1000; // remaining time in seconds
}
```

Comment: Is it okay from performance reasons to constantly save an array of timers in this way?

Comment: @gooner_dp You can keep the remaining seconds in the redux store and periodically update. That is totally fine. But I would avoid unnecessarily reading and writing the localStorage.